# How to download report through URL to database

Tags: javascript, jasperserver

I have report, which when I run through web browser, using URL displays correctly.

http://my.server:8081/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=%2Freports%2FTestRep_TK&standAlone=true&ParentFolderUri=/reports&repLocale=cs_CZ&j_acegi_security_check&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin&output=pdf&destination=download

I'm trying to download this report into Oracle database using following finction:

PROCEDURE load_binary_from_url2(p_url IN VARCHAR2) AS
      l_blob BLOB;
   BEGIN
      -- http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/retrieving-html-and-binaries-into-tables-over-http.php
      l_blob := HTTPURITYPE.createuri(p_url).getblob();

```
  -- Insert the data into the table.
  INSERT INTO dokumentacia
     (object_id,
      TIMESTAMP,
      doc_name,
      doc_blob)
  VALUES
     (next_object_id,
      SYSDATE,
      'Test rep.pdf',
      l_blob);
 END load_binary_from_url2;
```

This procedure works fine, when I have any URL to pdf file stored online.

Problem is when I try to call any jasper report stored at JSS. Then it return an HTML page code with an error, instead of pdf file as expected.

```
<pre>       
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">      
<html>    
  <head>        
    <title>TIBCO Jaspersoft: JasperReports Server Error Page
    </title>        
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">        
    <!--
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
            -->        
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href='/jasperserver/_themes/A2F41A5B/images/favicon.ico' />        
    <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
            -->         
    <meta name = "viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var JRS = {};
    var __jrsConfigs__ = {
        i18n: {},
        localContext: {},
        isIPad: "",
        contextPath: "/jasperserver",
        publicFolderUri: "/public",
        tempFolderUri: "/temp",
        organizationId: "",
        commonReportGeneratorsMetadata: [],
        templatesFolderUri: '',
        defaultTemplateUri: '',
        advNotSelected: "ADH_162_NULL_SAVE_REPORT_SOURCE",
        templateNotSelected: "ADH_162_NULL_SELECT_TEMPLATE_SOURCE",
        calendar: {
            userLocale: "cs_CZ",
            timepicker: {
                timeText: 'Time:',
                hourText: 'Hour',
                minuteText: 'Minute',
                secondText: 'Second',
                currentText: 'Now',
                closeText: 'Close',
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                separator:' '
            },
            i18n: {
                bundledCalendarTimeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
                bundledCalendarFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            }
        },
        webHelpModuleState: {
            contextMap: {"default":"100","bi_overview":"100","login":"150","legacy_dashboard":"200","ad_hoc":"300","domain":"500","search":"600","analysis":"700","admin":"800","repo":"900","dashboard":"1000"},
            hostURL: 'http://help.jaspersoft.com/js-help-v6-en/',
            pagePrefix: 'Default_CSH.htm#'
        },
        urlContext: "/jasperserver",
        defaultSearchText: "",
        serverIsNotResponding: "The server is slow or isn't responding. Confirm that you want to continue."
    };
    // dirty hack to get path to current theme
    __jrsConfigs__.currentThemePath = "_themes/A2F41A5B/theme.css".split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/");
    __jrsConfigs__.isProVersion = "false" === "true" ? true : false;
    __jrsConfigs__.userLocale = "cs_CZ";
    __jrsConfigs__.isFreeOrLimitedEdition = false;
    //TODO: get it from the server
    __jrsConfigs__.avaliableLocales = ["de", "en", "es", "fr", "it", "ja", "ro", "zh_TW", "zh_CN"];
    __jrsConfigs__.localeSettings = {
        locale: "cs_CZ",
        decimalSeparator: "" || ".",
        groupingSeparator: "" || ",",
        timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        timestampSeparator: " "
    };
    //Heartbeat
    __jrsConfigs__.heartbeatInitOptions = {
        baseUrl: "/jasperserver",
        showDialog: false,
        sendClientInfo: false
    };


            __jrsConfigs__.initAdditionalUIComponents = true;



    __jrsConfigs__.flowExecutionKey = "e3s1";
    if (window.localStorage && window.localStorage.previousPageHash){
        window.location.hash = window.localStorage.previousPageHash;
        delete window.localStorage.previousPageHash;
    }
</script>         
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jasperserver/optimized-scripts/bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jasperserver/optimized-scripts/require.config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "/jasperserver/optimized-scripts"
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jasperserver/optimized-scripts/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jasperserver/scripts/bower_components/prototype/dist/prototype.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">
        define("prototype", $);
    </script>                                                              
<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["errorPage"]);
        </script>     
  </head>             
  <body id="serverError" class="">    
    <div id="banner" class="banner" style="">        
      <div id="systemMessageConsole" style="display:none">            
        <p id="systemMessage">Close
        </p>        
      </div>        
      <div id="logo" class="sectionLeft">
      </div>        
      <div class="sectionLeft">                            
        <div id="mainNavigation" class="menu horizontal primaryNav">                   
          <ul id="navigationOptions" data-tab-index="2" data-component-type="navigation">                       
            <li id="main_home" tabIndex="-1" class="leaf">
              <p class="wrap button">
                <span class="icon">
                </span>Home
              </p>
            </li>                                                   
            <li id="main_library" tabIndex="-1" class="leaf">
              <p class="wrap button">
                <span class="icon">
                </span>Library
              </p>
            </li>                                           
          </ul>               
        </div>                      
      </div>        
      <div class="sectionRight searchContainer">            
        <!-- banner search -->             
        <span id="globalSearch" class="control searchLockup " data-tab-index='1' data-component-type='search'>    
          <label for="searchInput" class="offLeft">Search
          </label>    
          <div class="wrap">
            <input type="text" class="" id="searchInput" tabIndex="-1"/>
          </div>    
          <b class="right">
            <a class="button searchClear"></a></b>    
          <a class="button search up"></a>
        </span>       
      </div>        
      <ul id="metaLinks" class="sectionRight">            
        <li id="userID">                                         
          <span id="casted">                                                     
          </span>                    jasperadmin&#32;User                              
        </li>                                      
        <li id="main_logOut" class="last">
          <a id="main_logOut_link">Log Out</a>
        </li>        
      </ul>    
    </div>    
    <div id="frame" style="">        
      <div class="content">            
        <!--/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/page.jsp revision A-->
        <div id="display" class="body oneColumn flow">    
          <a name="maincontent" id="maincontent"></a>              
          <!--/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/container.jsp revision A-->
          <div  class="column decorated primary" >               
            <div  class="content " >             
              <div  class="header " >            
                <div class="title">                Server Error             
                </div>                                 
              </div>                 
              <div id="errorPageContent" class="body  " >                                               
                <div id="stepDisplay">                                             
                  <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="e3s1"/>                                                                                       
                  <input type="hidden" name="_flowId" value=""/>                                            
                  <!-- BUG 10599 -->                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                  <fieldset class="row instructions">                                
                    <h3 id="clarification">The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.</h3>                            
                  </fieldset>                            
                  <fieldset class="row inputs oneColumn">                                 
                    <!--/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/container.jsp revision A-->
                    <div  class="column noHeader primary" >                            
                      <div  class="content " >             
                        <div  class="header " >            
                          <div class="title">                             
                          </div>                                  
                        </div>                 
                        <div  class="body  " >                                                                                                                                                                
                          <div id="errorMessages">                                                    <h3>Error Message</h3>                                                    
                            <p class="large">java.lang.NullPointerException
                            </p>                                                
                          </div>                                                                                                                                                                                         
                          <div id="completeStackTrace" style="padding-bottom:350px;">                                                        <h3>Error Trace</h3>                                                        
                            <p style="white-space:normal;">java.lang.NullPointerException     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.DefaultHttpUtils.encodeContentFilename(DefaultHttpUtils.java:70)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.AbstractReportExporter.getFilename(AbstractReportExporter.java:291)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ReportPdfExporter.setAdditionalResponseHeaders(ReportPdfExporter.java:63)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.AbstractReportExporter.exportBuffered(AbstractReportExporter.java:191)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.AbstractReportExporter.export(AbstractReportExporter.java:99)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ReportExporterAction.export(ReportExporterAction.java:158)     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor629.invoke(Unknown Source)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.springframework.webflow.action.DispatchMethodInvoker.invoke(DispatchMethodInvoker.java:98)     at org.springframework.webflow.action.MultiAction.doExecute(MultiAction.java:123)     at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)     at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)     at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)     at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)     at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)     at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)     at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:155)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:193)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:535)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:225)     at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor324.invoke(Unknown Source)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)     at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.launchExecution(Unknown Source)     at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)     at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.doFilter(StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.java:163)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.IPadSupportFilter.doFilter(IPadSupportFilter.java:67)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.common.JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.doFilter(JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.java:157)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:143)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:99)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:210)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:43)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:210)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:53)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSCsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(JSCsrfGuardFilter.java:83)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.WebAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebAppSecurityFilter.java:80)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.MultipartRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(MultipartRequestWrapperFilter.java:95)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:43)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.encryption.EncryptionFilter.doFilter(EncryptionFilter.java:150)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.SessionDecoratorFilter.doFilter(SessionDecoratorFilter.java:63)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)     at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.P3PFilter.doFilter(P3PFilter.java:43)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
                            </p>                                                    
</pre>
```

Any suggestion, what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi, how are you calling your report? In other webapp? Have you consider to store your reports on filesystem, on protected/secure directories, and only store report name/location on your database?

Comment: Hi Alejandro,
At the moment a report is being called from oracle database directly. Suggested solution, to generate a rep in local directory would be even better solution. So there are 2 steps to follow:
1. Generate a report to local protected directory
2. Once report is created, save an access URL in database.

Do you have any example for this process?

I think a problem in initial question is that db tries to call/download report even when it not fully prepared by jasper soft server.

Thanks,
Tomas

Comment: Exact. JasperServer doesn't provide direct Url for reports. Reports in final format (pdf, excel) are generated in several steps, depending on web service used for report generation (Rest or Soap). You need to use this Jasper Server web services with any programming language on backend to generate and save pdfs, excel, and finally give to your clients Access to final files. See http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-rest-web-service-api. In github there are many samples ready to use

Comment: The correct way to do this is using the web services e.g. REST_V2 to get the report. Please see the documentation JasperReports-Server-Web-Services-Guide.pdf